# Insert HTML tags into a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a `contentEditable` div.

The problem is when I type in HTML tags, say, `<h1>` Then the angle brackets get replaced with their entity names `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the DOM.

How do I prevent that from happening?

I want the actual tags to be inserted instead of the HTML entity.

Here's a jsFiddle to depict the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/m0xbd2j9/28/

Comment: You can't... It's rich text editor.

Comment: Are there other ways of doing the same? @Praveen

Comment: You can have a plain textbox to get the html and convert it into rich text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is expected to happen. Otherwise, users could easily mess HTML of your page.

If you REALLY want to do that (I don't recommend you to do so in production) you can intercept keyup event and perform a replace over element contents. Something like (untested example using jquery for the sake of brevity):

```
var editable = $("#editableDiv");
editable.on("keyup", function(event) {
    // TODO: Better check if event key is either "<" or ">"
    // to avoid extra processing if not necessary.
    editable.html(
        editable.html()
            .replace("&lt;", "<")
            .replace("&gt;", ">")
    );
});
```

On the other hand, if what you want is simply to read that contents (not render it) as unescaped HTML, you can simply do the same replacement on the reading process.

**HINT:** ON the backend you probably have some library functions, like [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) in PHP, which does just that and much more for you.

Comment: Works as said, but, the cursor has a weird movement... https://jsfiddle.net/m0xbd2j9/56/

Comment: I missed that detail (did I said it was untested example? ;-)). But I think you could overcome it by reading cursor position previously and fix it after the change. I don't know exactly which is the issue you are experiencing, but I can imagine it: On one hand, replacing contents can, depending on the browser, radically change cursor position (hence the need to save previous position) and, on the other hand, you are removing a bunch of characters to add single one. So you also should fix that gap in calculation... Inspect the event paramenter to find information you need.